# How to prove this integral problem?

Tags: integration

For $0<k<1$ put $$K(k)=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\text{d}t}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 t}} \quad \textbf{and} \quad k'=\sqrt{1-k^2}\in(0,1)$$

- Prove that $$K(k)=\frac{1}{1+k}K\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right)$$
- Prove that $$K(k)=\frac{2}{1+k'}K\left(\frac{1-k'}{1+k'}\right)$$

I have no idea that how to solve this integral.

Comment: Note that the question does not ask you to solve the integral. You must work with $K\left(\frac{2\sqrt k}{1+k}\right)$ and try to relate it to $K(k)$.

Comment: This is what is called a "complete elliptic integral of the first kind".  Historically, it is one of the earliest integrals that was encountered for which there is no elementary anti-derivative.  So we can't write a function to evaluate using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, *but* it is still possible to use properties of the integrand to derive identities concerning this integral.

Comment: How to prove the second one?

Answer (score 2):

We're given:
$$K(k) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1 - k^2\sin^2t}}$$
So then:
$$\frac{1}{1+k}K\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right) = \frac{1}{1+k} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k}\right)^2\sin^2t}}$$

Simplify this and show that it equals $K(k)$.  Proceed similarly for the other problem.

Comment: You wrote "Simplify this and show that it equals $K(k)$."   Yet that simplification is the entire essence of the problem.

Comment: It's only the entire essence of the problem for people who know what they're supposed to do in this problem.  OP suggested he or she didn't even know how to begin.  So I figured I would put OP on the right track.  If OP still needs help then OP should feel free to ask me for further clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I will show the first result using a substitution of 
$$\tan t = \dfrac{\sin 2 \theta}{k + \cos 2 \theta}.$$
Under this substitution it can be shown (it is a bit of a slog) that
$$dt = \frac{2(1 + k \cos 2\theta)}{1 + 2k \cos 2\theta + k^2} \, d\theta,$$
while the term appearing in the denominator of the integral becomes
$$1 - k^2 \sin^2 t = \frac{(1 + k \cos 2\theta)^2}{1 + 2k \cos 2\theta + k^2},$$
The limits of integration remain unchanged.

Thus
\begin{align*}
K(k) &= 2 \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{1 + k \cos 2\theta}{1 + 2k \cos 2 \theta + k^2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{1 + 2k \cos 2 \theta + k^2}}{1 + k \cos 2\theta} \, d\theta\\
&= 2 \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1 + 2k \cos 2\theta + k^2}}\\
&= 2 \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{(1 + k)^2 - 4k \sin^2 \theta}}\\
&= \frac{2}{1 + k} \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1 - \left (\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{1 + k} \right )^2 \sin^2 \theta}}, \quad {\rm since} \,\, 0 < k < 1\\
&= \frac{2}{1 + k} K \left (\frac{2 \sqrt{k}}{1 + k} \right ),
\end{align*}
as required to show.